# how to get the width and height from array of bytes of image by C#?

Tags: c#

```
Byte[] fileData;

FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);//class for files
fileData = new byte[fs.Length];//the number of elemnts of array is the lenght of the file
fs.Read(fileData, 0, fileData.Length);//write the content of the file  on the array fileData 
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Adding text to explain your problem, the expected result and the result you actually get will help others to help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Image newImage = Image.FromStream(fs);
newImage.Width
newImage.Height
```

I think the code is pretty self-explanatory. Just put it somewhere in between opening and closing the filestream.

EDIT:

```
byte[] fileData = new byte[4];
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open);
fs.Seek(18, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fs.Read(fileData, 0, 4);
uint width = BitConverter.ToUInt32(fileData, 0);
fs.Read(fileData, 0, 4);
uint height = BitConverter.ToUInt32(fileData, 0);
fs.Close();
```

Comment: I need to get the width and height from the array by reading the bytes  and calculate them

Comment: You didn't even mention what type of image do you have. It's REALLY hard to get information from bytes because every image format has a different header. You need to get signature of the processed image, that will give you image format (like PNG, BMP etc.). If you know what the format is, you can get things like width and height that's saved in on a certain position (check image format specification for more details). I can't provide any code sample, because Image class solves everything.

Comment: @ProMohammedGomaa why do you need to do that?

Comment: the type of image is BMP @MartinCerman

Comment: I added some code to my answer, everything's hardcoded but it should work for BMP images.